# How to suppress all warnings in window of executable file generated by pyinstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I have generated an executable file from a python file using pyinstaller. The program works how it is supposed to work but there is this warning message it appears in the window that I would like to hide.

The following line does suppress all warning messages when the python file is run within the IDE.

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

But in the window of the executable file, this warning is displayed:

```
\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:627: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are going to using a customized `spec` building file, you can just add following line to your `spec` files to suppress these startup warnings(according to https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#giving-run-time-python-options):

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      [('W ignore', None, 'OPTION')],
      # ...
```

Since a `spec` file is actually a python script, you can replace `pathex` with `os.getcwd()` and make sure you've already import `os` module in your `spec` file.

I've tried on `Windows 10` with `Python 3.7.4` and `pyinstaller 3.5`. It works!

---

Since you've provided a customized `spec` file, your basic building command should change to:

```
pyinstaller xxx.spec
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, it works!! Many thanks. Sorry, I couldn't check this earlier.

Comment: Any way to do this with an existing build, without building again?

Comment: @Eren I'm afraid you can't. Since it is already an executable binary file and the option should be affect the way to build it.