# Pyinstaller Matlab deprecation warning

Tags: python, pyinstaller

After compiling my python script through pyinstaller with:

```
    pyinstaller --onefile --ico=hub_blue.ico SearchSet.py
```

I get the warning:

> D:\Users\cdoyle\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\sitepackages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:627: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
>
> The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
>   exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)

---

It doesn't show when running the file from the my terminal, only after compiling. I've used in my code to try and prevent it but doesn't seem to do the trick

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

---

I'm importing the following librarys:

```
import os
import openpyxl as oxl
import pandas as pd
import time as t
import progress.bar as pbar
```

---

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question in [How to suppress all warnings in window of executable file generated by pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701417/how-to-suppress-all-warnings-in-window-of-executable-file-generated-by-pyinstall)

your can suppress the warning

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
  a.scripts,
  [('W ignore', None, 'OPTION')],
  # ...
```